# Spotfire - All outputs were removed with script R

Tags: r, ironpython, spotfire

I have a problem with 2 script R.

I created an R script that allows me to duplicate an existing table by adding 3 columns.

```
#Create new table
output<-table

#Create New columns
output$NumRow<-c(1:nrow(output))
output$LCL_USER<-table$LCL
output$UCL_USER<-table$UCL
```

I created a second R script that allows me to change the values ​​in the columns.

```
#Change specific row in table 

numRow<-as.numeric(SnumRow)
numcol<-as.character(ScolName)
value<-as.numeric(newValue)

#Replace value
output[numRow,numcol]<-value
```

My problem is when I use the second script it deletes first because all outputs are deleted.

Error message:

```
The data function 'nameScript' was removed because all of its outputs were removed.
```

Can I have to duplicate the table and insert columns with a ironpython script? How ?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. Even if I think that you found a bypass by the time, I provide an answer for posterity.

The easiest way to fix this is :

1. Creating a new document property (nammed `myProperty` in the next steps of this example) with type integer
2. Assigning a value (integer) to the document property in the R data function (`myProperty <- 1L`)
3. Adding variable `myProperty` as an Output parameter of the data function
4. Editing parameters of the script to link variable `myProperty` with document property `myProperty`

---

This issue is caused by a data function having output being part of the output of another, that's why this fix works. You can also duplicate the data table as you've figured out but I prefer to keep only one data table for performance and resources reasons.